# How add textarea content in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

when i am submit input field inserted correctly but in textarea only pre /pre inserted not textarea inserted can anybody help me

**FORM**

```
 <form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="e" name="e">
    <textarea id="txtEditor" name="a"></textarea>   
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/>
     </form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$connect= new mysqli("localhost","root","","database") or die("ERROR:could not connect to the database!!!");

extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{
$msg="<pre>$a</pre>";

$query = "INSERT INTO questions (e, a) VALUES ('$e', '$msg')";
$connect->query($query);
echo "Data saved";  
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try to `echo $a`?

Comment: extract on user supplied data is INCREDIBLY DANGEROUS

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `extract()`.i recommend try something like this because this code is readable and simple.

```
$connect= new mysqli("localhost","root","","database") or die("ERROR:could not connect to the database!!!");
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $e=$_POST['e'];
    $msg=$_POST['a'];   
    $query = "INSERT INTO questions (e,a) VALUES ('$e','$msg')";
    if ($connect->query($query)) {
        echo 'data save';
    }
}
```

> NOTE:given code is open to sql injection attack you should use
>   prepared statement.

Comment: textarea  content not inserted

Comment: Why are you recommending an approach which you know to be insecure?

Comment: @Strawberry i am recommending to remove extract(). rest all is same.why are you trying to create issue .OP is trying to use vulnerable query.i recommended to use prepared statement.

Comment: if you want to dwonvoted it you'r welcome.but give specific reason dont give me something like this.

Comment: you know this is not code writing service.you can give advise or suggestion to this .if question is not related to security.OP wants to ask about solution.given solution is ok but also recommend to use prepared statement.what is wrong here.

Comment: No error form submitted correctly but in database inserted only <pre></pre> tags not $msg content ($msg= "<pre>".$_POST['a']."</pre>";)

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" action="file_name.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="e" name="e">
    <textarea id="txtEditor" name="a"></textarea>   
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/>
     </form>
```

**file_name.php:**

```
$connect= new mysqli("localhost","root","","database") or die("ERROR:could not connect to the database!!!");

//extract($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{

$msg= "<pre>".$_POST['a']."</pre>";
$e = $_POST['e']; // you are not declare this
$query = "INSERT INTO questions (e, a) VALUES ('$e', '$msg')";
$insert = $connect->query($query);
if($insert == true)
{
echo "Data saved";  
}
}
```

> Note: Make sure your `a` field should be text datatype in database

Comment: What datatype used for `a` field in questions table

Comment: No error form submitted correctly but in database inserted only <pre></pre> tags not $msg content   ($msg= "<pre>".$_POST['a']."</pre>";)

Comment: Okay then insert only textarea values